# Export Screaming Frog data with semicolons

Tags: web-crawler

I'm exporting Screaming Frog crawl data but I can't find the config settings so that it exports the csv or xls with semicolon separators rather than commas, which put the columns out of alignment when I open the file.

Edit : Right now I have to open as a text file and replace all ; with | and then replace all "," with ";" to get round the columns problem.

Does anyone know where the settings are for this ?

Thanks